# Delete lines from a string that appears in other string

Tags: python, string

I have two strings, here an example:

String1:

```
example1
example2
example3
example4
```

and the second string:

```
example5
example1
example25
```

The idea is to delete all the lines that are in both strings, from the first one, and the result must be something like this:

String1:

```
example2
example3
example4
```

The result must be a string too.

Comment: Could you show your work?

Comment: convert to a set of strings. then a-b.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to iterate through the strings you want to remove. Then directly remove those strings on the first variable.

```
first = """example1
example2
example3
example4""".split()
second = """example5
example1
example25""".split()
for rem in second:
    try:first.remove(rem)
    except ValueError:pass
print('\n'.join(first))
```

or if you don't want to have a try/except you can check if the string you want to delete is found in your first string

```
first = """example1
example2
example3
example4""".split()
second = """example5
example1
example25""".split()
for rem in second:
    if rem in first:
        first.remove(rem)
print('\n'.join(first))
```

The last example would be to use list comprehension but seems @azro has tackled that already.

output

```
example2
example3
example4
```

Answer (score 2):

You could simple `set` operation like following but this doesn't preserve order

```
result = "\n".join(set(s1.splitlines()) - set(s2.splitlines()))
print(result)
```

So better iterate over the lines of first, and keep if not in second

```
s1 = """example1
example2
example3
example4"""

s2 = """example5
example1
example25"""

avoid = set(s2.splitlines())
result = "\n".join(x for x in s1.splitlines() if x not in avoid)
print(result)
```

Comment: nice dealing with order preservation.